# Quando utilizar "mim" ou "eu"?

Tags: caso-gramatical, conjugação-pronominal

Quando eu devo utilizar **mim** ou **eu**?

Qual frase é correta?

- Faça comida para mim comer.
- Faça comida para eu comer.

E entre estas, qual a correta?

- Vocês podem fazer isso para mim?
- Vocês podem fazer isso para eu?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

"Mim" não conjuga verbo.

Logo, para saber se é adequado usar "mim" ou "eu" perceba se você está tentando conjugar algum verbo com essa palavra.

- Faça comida para eu comer.
- Faça comida para nós comermos.
- <s>Faça comida para mim comer.</s>

O "mim" é um pronome pessoal oblíquo tônico.

> Os pronomes pessoais oblíquos tônicos são sempre precedidos de uma preposição e devem ser usados quando, na frase, o substantivo que substituem tem função de objeto indireto. Assim, a expressão para mim deverá ser usada quando assume a função de objeto indireto.

Logo, o correto é:

- Vocês podem fazer isso para mim?

Fonte: [Dicio, o Dicionário Online de Português](http://duvidas.dicio.com.br/para-mim-ou-para-eu/)

Comment: Costumo utilizar essa frase...

Comment: @LucasMotta vou completar minha resposta

Answer (score 6):

## Para Mim

Usado normalmente para encerrar a frase.

> Faça comida para mim.
>
> Vocês podem fazer isso para mim?

Mas não necessariamente precisa encerrar a frase. É o pronome pessoal usado para indicar que a ação da frase é endereçada ao autor da frase:

Vocês podem fazer isso para mim ou para ele?

## Para eu...

Usado normalmente com um objeto direto.

> Faça comida para eu comer.
>
> Vocês podem fazer isso para eu comer?

Comment: Nem sempre, "Você fez comida para mim ou para ele"?

Comment: @Math. Valeu. Coloquei mais coisas.